# My servers status suddenly got PROVISIONING in Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

After restarting some of my servers in Google Compute Engine and try to connect them via ssh they are all in PROVISIONING status for more than 4 hours!

According to google documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances#checkmachinestatus

> PROVISIONING - Resources are being reserved for the instance. The
>   instance isn't running yet.

Well, they were working for more than one month.

I tried several time to turn them off via gcloud command-line tool but it didn't work.

check for any problem in Google Cloud Status, nothing is mentioned there for today:
https://status.cloud.google.com

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

In some cases where your "PROVISIONING" takes too long, depending on the region/zone/time you try to create your instances in, the issue could be related to (generally, but not limited to. I'm just giving some ideas):

- Limited resources in that zone, at that time, could cause the instances to hang in the provisioning status. Google usually takes care of this pretty quickly, within a few days or something. I don't have exact information but they add more resources to the zone and the issue disappears. They also add new zones and such, so it could be worth moving to a new zone if more resources are readily available there.
- Temporary issue that should resolve itself.

A few questions I have for you:

1. Is this still happing? Considering the fact that you posted about a month ago, I assume you've gotten past this issue and everything is working as expected at this time. If so, I'd recommend posting an answer yourself with details on what happened or what you did to fix it. You can then accept your own answer so that others can see what fixed it.
2. Have you tried creating instances in different zones to see if you have the problem everywhere or just within a specific one?

All in all, this is usually a transient issue, based on my experience with the Google Cloud Platform. If this is still causing trouble for you, give us some more information on what is currently happening and the community might be able to help better.

Comment: thanks @Boyan ! until now I found some temporary solutions. I will post update as soon as I get to some final one